# Core Data: Search for existence of a single word

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have an iPhone Core Data database with over 170,000 words in it. Just words, nothing else. When I preform a pretty complex regular expression fetch, it only takes about 10 seconds to get the returned results. Yet when I use a predicate like below, it takes about 7 seconds. Shouldn't it take far less than that amount of time to complete the request? With the below example I'm simply checking that the particular word, in this case "apple" exists in the database. Is there a better way to do this?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word LIKE 'apple'"];
```

Comment: Whoops... if I do NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word == 'apple'"]; that returns in a couple of milliseconds. Much better.

Comment: yep, RyJ is on the ball with that. For any fancier pattern matching, you will need a "Directed Acyclic Word Graph".

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"'apple' <=  word AND word < 'applf'"];
```